# Atiyah--Singer for the Complex Projective Line

Tags: complex-geometry, chern-classes

I'm trying to understand Atiyah--Singer by looking at the usual starting point of $CP^1$ and the Dirac--Dolbeault operator. If I've reduced everything down correctly, then in this case the theorem gives
$$
\text{Index}(\overline{\partial} + \overline{\partial}^*) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{CP^1} \text{ch}_1(T(CP^1)),
$$
where ch$_1(T(CP^1))$ is the first Chern class of the tangent bundle $CP^1$. I would like a direct explanation of why this is true.

Comment: For the RHS, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern_class#Example:_the_complex_tangent_bundle_of_the_Riemann_sphere

Comment: I don't know helpful my cryptic comment will be, but you can compute both sides explicitly in this case. The right side is $1$ because $ch_1=c_1=2$ (times fundamental class). So is the left: use the 
Dolbeault resolution and the fact the holomorphic functions on $CP^1$ are constant...

Comment: @ Steve, Donu: Thanks for your answers, but I'm not really looking to show that both sides are equal (as you show, this is easy) I'm looking for someone who understands the Atiyah--Singer proof to show what it reduces down to in this simple case.

Comment: Yes, I see. I have to admit, I've only really looked as special cases,
e.g Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch.
In any case, my (limited) understanding is there are two steps. The first (and probably the deepest) is to see that there is a universal formula in Chern classes of the manifold and symbol. Then to discover the explicit form by computing enough examples.
Hopefully, someone else gave give you more insight.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you want - the Atiyah-Singer index theorem for the Dolbeault operator on a Kahler manifold is precisely the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem.  So for $CP^1$ it looks like you're asking about the classical Riemann-Roch theorem.  The proof of Atiyah-Singer doesn't really tell you anything new about complex geometry (in fact, if you follow the global proof then the first step is to embed $CP^1$ into Euclidean space...), and the proof that Atiyah-Singer implies Riemann-Roch just involves playing around with Clifford algebras and characteristic classes.

Comment: But the Atiyah--Singer only gives you H-R-R after you use the Hodge decomp to show that the index of the Dolbeault operator is the Euler characteristic. No? What Atiyah--Singer does is to show that the index of the Dolbeault operator is the integral of the Todd class over $CP^1$. No? In any case, this is what I want: a direct explanation of why the index of the Dolbeault operator is the integral of the Todd class over $CP^1$.  